# How does the d3js library register itself into the runtime, with its own name

Tags: javascript, d3.js, design-patterns

Can someone explain this code :

```
(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
      (factory((global.d3 = global.d3 || {})));
}(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';
```

specifically in terms of how this particular library register itself in the runtime with its own name (which is 'd3').

I figure that this is more/less an IIFE pattern. But can't get to work out on how it register itself with its own name in the runtime.

Comment: is your questions specifically for `d3js` only? I think that's also how
 *Vue* registers itself, and many more js libs actually, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The name of this is UMD: https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/ This question has nothing to do with D3 and, being off topic, I'm voting to close it.

Comment: Turns out this is the established way (in the form of UMD) of environment/host detection, which in turn is used for module loading. It has been many years since I usedJavascript, back in the "geocities" days, so understandably a lot has changed.